# ZF2 form to change multiple parameters

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

Using the ZF2 Album module as an example, how do I create a form to be placed on the index view that would be able to filter the records by two or more parameters?   Let’s say that the data had a `genre` column and `year` column, and we wanted the index view to have a form with two corresponding select elements.  The form is a simple form, so we don’t want a submit button; instead we want the user selection to trigger the form action.  The controller sets `$genre-filter` and `$year` based on input from the router, and those values 1) filter the data that is sent to the view and 2) set the ‘selected’ option of the select element in the form.

How do I make this happen?  I have a number of questions I can’t find information on:

1. How do I make the select elements trigger the form action?  In HTML this is done by adding
   `onchange='this.form.submit()'` to the select tag.  How do I do it in ZF2?
2. How do I indicate which of the options in the select element is the
   ‘selected’ (current default) option?  In HTML this is done by adding
   `'selected'` to an option tag.  How do I do it in ZF2?
3. How do I write the form action script?

Here’s what I have so far:

```
// in the controller:

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

// ... //

$genre-filter = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('genre');
$year-filter  = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('year');

// ... //

$genre = new Element\Select('genre');
$genre->setValueOptions(array(
   'all' => 'all',
   'jazz' => 'jazz',
   'punk' => 'punk',
   'emo' => 'emo',
   // ... //
));

$year = new Element\Select('year');
$year->setValueOptions(array(
   'all' => 'all',
   '2001' => '2001',
   '2002' => '2002',
   '2003' => '2003',
));

$form = new Form('event-filter');
$form->add($genre);
$form->add($year);
```

and

```
// in the view script:

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo "genre: " . $this->formSelect($genre);
echo "year: " . $this->formSelect($year);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

I assume that the form action is written something like this:

```
// in the controller:

$genre-selection = $this->getRequest()->getPost('genre', 'all');
$year-selection  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('year', 'all');

return $this->redirect()->toRoute('albums', array('action'=>'index', 'genre' => $genre-selection, 'year' => $year-selection);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **1.** How do I make the select elements trigger the form action? In HTML this is done by adding onchange='this.form.submit()' to the select tag. How do I do it in ZF2?

You can specify attributes for individual form elements when defining them:

```
$genre = new Element\Select('genre');
$genre->setAttributes(array(
    'onchange' => 'this.form.submit();'
));
```

However it would be better to remove this from the HTML completely and do it unobtrusively. Add to your JS file:

```
if (document.getElementById('event-filter')) {
    $('#event-filter select').change(function(e) {
        $('#event-filter').submit();
    });
}
```

> **2.** How do I indicate which of the options in the select element is the ‘selected’ (current default) option? In HTML this is done by adding 'selected' to an option tag. How do I do it in ZF2?

```
$form = new Form('event-filter');
$form->setData(array(
    'genre' => 'jazz',
    'year' => '2002'
));
```

> **3.** How do I write the form action script?

This really depends how you're loading the data already, but if you have any specific problems with that perhaps we can help.